# Connecting interface builder to the code in Xcode 4

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I created a new project in Xcode 4 using the "Cocoa Application" template and added a few UI elements as seen below:

[image]

Now that I've designed this basic interface I'm at a loss for how to actually respond to user events for that button. What type of class should I create and how do I connect that class to IB?

I realize I could read the 100s of pages of Apple documentation that explains all this, but those tend to be too verbose and slightly overwhelming. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: Those pages of documentation will teach you how to do things properly. You should read them, or an equivalent book or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Ctrl+Drag connections from your controls to actions (defined in code) of the other objects in your XIB file. Cocoa is a powerful framework and Xcode is a wonderful tool, but you're going to have to do *some* reading to get started. Here's a good site for beginners: [Cocoa Dev Central](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/). I recommend you study the tutorials in this order:

- Learn Objective-C
- Learn Cocoa
- Learn Cocoa II
- Objective-C Style I
- Objective-C Style II

Then you can do some of the more advanced ones. The tutorials are designed for Xcode 3, but they should not be hard to follow, and it you run into problems, Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Control drag from each UI element to the assistant editor.

If you select outlet then it will generate the property and the ivar along with the proper memory management in the .m.

If you select action then it will create a method that will be called when your UI element is interacted with.

I would post a decent picture but I do not have enough reputation...